# Displaying JSON Values on webpage

Tags: javascript, python, html, json

I have been in Tech Support for 20 plus years and wanted to give Python, Javascript a go so frogive my question and total noobyness but have been scratching my head witht he following question. Please could you help with what is highly likely blaringly obvious?

I have a python script that outputs values to a JSON file (msitc.json) which is below:

`{"hostname": "MSITC1", "uuid": 113780617491, "system": {"name": "Windows", "version": "10"}, "uptime": 9975, "cpu_count": 12, "cpu_usage": 3.8, "memory_total": 51451674624}`

I have tried many different HTML/Javascript/PHP in order to display the data gathered from various examples all over the net below is the latest on I am fiddling abvout with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>JSON Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myData"></div>
    <script>
        fetch('msitc.json')
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function (data) {
                appendData(data);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log('error: ' + err);
            });
        function appendData(data) {
            var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.innerHTML = 'Name: ' + data[i].hostname + ' ' + data[i].uuid;
                mainContainer.appendChild(div);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The JSON data displays in Chrome Console but cant see it on the webpade

I know I am doing something pretty stupid as I am just starting to learn this stuff so any advice would be great - Thanks.

Comment: If you need to transform JSON to string try ```JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)```

Comment: Your page is normally loaded and shows some name and uuid in my case.

Comment: Your 'data' is not an `Array` but a `JSON` string. First use `JSON.stringify()` to convert it to text. Then create a child element using `appendChild()` method. See [appending a child](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp).

Comment: Thank You but where would I put that in the code please?

Comment: does your json file contains only one json object or there are array of object?

Comment: e.g. MSITC.json would be always have this structure `{"hostname": "MSITC1", "uuid": 113780617491, "system": {"name": "Windows", "version": "10"}, "uptime": 9975, "cpu_count": 12, "cpu_usage": 3.8, "memory_total": 51451674624}` or it is gonna be like  `[{"hostname": "MSITC1", "uuid": 113780617491, "system": {"name": "Windows", "version": "10"}, "uptime": 9975, "cpu_count": 12, "cpu_usage": 3.8, "memory_total": 51451674624},{"hostname": "MSITC1", "uuid": 113780617491, "system": {"name": "Windows", "version": "10"}, "uptime": 9975, "cpu_count": 12, "cpu_usage": 3.8, "memory_total": 51451674624}]`

Comment: Thanks - the output from my python script dispolays some array i.e [] full .json pasted below: (wouldnt let me paste all of it so below is last part for example.

Comment: ``` {"name": "vEthernet (Default Switch)", "mac": "00-15-5D-DB-5D-0D", "address": "172.22.192.1", "address6": "fe80::b13e:b86f:3746:e58f", "netmask": "255.255.240.0"}, {"name": "Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1", "mac": "", "address": "127.0.0.1", "address6": "::1", "netmask": "255.0.0.0"}], "timestamp": "2020-09-26T07:31:30+00:00"}```